# How do Import from an xml while avoiding button click interruption

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application made up of comboboxes and textboxes .They are grouped into two groupboxes.

The first groupbox1 being purely user inputs.
[image]

The second groupbox2 is of results based on the inputs ,it is revealed after a button click *calculate* on groupbox1. Everything works well . Code below is a snippet ,the full block is too long to paste here.

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
               Variables.maximumcvof3 = Math.Max(double.Parse(txtRFCMaxF.Text),Math.Max(double.Parse(txtRFCMinF.Text), double.Parse(txtRFCNF.Text)));
                Variables.maximumvelocityof3 = Math.Max(Math.Max(double.Parse(txtVVNF.Text), double.Parse(txtVVMinF.Text)), double.Parse(textBox10.Text));
                
                Variables.maximumnoiseof3 = Math.Max(Math.Max(double.Parse(txtAPSNF.Text), double.Parse(txtAPSMinF.Text)), double.Parse(txtAPSMaxF.Text));

                        groupBox9.Visible = false;
                        button2.Visible = false;
                        groupBox1.Visible = false;
                        groupBox2.Visible = true;
                        button3.Visible = false;
                        button1.Visible = true;
                        button4.Visible = true;
if (double.Parse(comboBox11.SelectedItem.ToString()) < 4.95)
                    {
                        cmbTType.Items.Clear();
                        cmbTType.Items.Add("Microflow");
                        cmbTType.Items.Add("Anticav 1");
                        cmbTType.Items.Add("Anticav 2");
                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmbTType.Items.Clear();
                        cmbTType.Items.Add("Standard Parabolic");
                        cmbTType.Items.Add("Anticav 1");
                        cmbTType.Items.Add("Anticav 2");
                       
                    }
     }
```

[image]

I have an *export* button on groupbox2 which "**serializes**" all the values on both groupboxes and saves in an xml file. This works well.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    dialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    dialog.FileName = "sizing";

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        FormSerialisor.Serialise(this, dialog.FileName + "");
    }

}
```

I have an import button on groupbox1 which "**deserializes**" a previously saved xml file.

```
  using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FormSerialisor.Deserialise(this, dialog.FileName);
        }
    }
```

It works on the 1st groupbox but recalculates everything for the 2nd groupbox on clicking calculate. The problem is it doesn't autoselect user inputs in comboboxes because it assumes its a new calculation.

How do i click calculate after importing and get the xml values stored?

Comment: Would need to see how the calculate button works, since that seems to be the focus of the question.  It would be helpful to describe how your calculate button state works.  It could be as easy as enabling the calculate button after deserializing previous results, but impossible to tell without intimate knowledge.

Comment: The calculate button uses the user inputs on groupbox1 to populate the Textboxes and comboboxes on groupbox2. Some formulas used for this are too long and the actual code is over 500 lines. I had included a snippet which is representative of how the button works.

Comment: Is the root of the question "How do I trigger a click on the calculate button?" ?  If you do not need the sender and event args you can call the function with null for params eg `Button2_Click(null, null);` or move this common functionality into a new function you call from both sites.